# Connecting piecewise smooth functions using mollification.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, convolution, smooth-functions

Let's say I am given a function $f: \mathbb{R}\setminus (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined piecewise as

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
g(x) \quad x \geq 1 \\
h(x) \quad x \leq 0
\end{cases},$$

where $g$ and $h$ are smooth, that is, $C^\infty$ functions. How can I extend $f$ to a $C^\infty$ function on all of $\mathbb{R}$? Is there a way to use mollification to do this? Any solutions/references/help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the characteristics of your functions, like if both are [flat functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) at the edges of their domains, you could use a [smooth transition function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Smooth_transition_functions), as example,
$$q(x)=\begin{cases} 0,\quad x\leq 0,\\ 1,\quad x\geq 1,\\ \dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\dfrac{2x-1}{x^2-x}\right)},\ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

You could see it in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vgnxfzwpy8):
[image: Desmos example]